# vectorizing "if" in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have an array of probability over a classification

```
post <- c(0.73,0.69,0.44,0.55,0.67,0.47,0.08,0.15,0.45,0.35)
```

and I want to retrieve the predicted class.
right now I use

```
predicted <- function(post) { 
               function(threshold) {plyr::aaply(post, 1, 
                   function(x) {if(x >= threshold) '+' else '-'})}}
```

but that seems like something R would have a syntax for.

Is there some indexing expression that would be more direct ?

Comment: That has to be the most complicated implementation of `ifelse` I've ever seen. :)

Comment: Huh? What's your `predicted` function supposed to do?

Comment: @Thomas Took me a while: `predicted(post)(0.5)`.

Comment: So the result is `ifelse(post>.5,"+","-")`?

Comment: @joran  just to get a vectorized if that looks a bit overkill indeed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @joran suggests:

```
predicted <- function(post)
   function(threshold) 
      ifelse(post>threshold,"+","-")
```

I find the nestedness of the functions a little confusing.

```
ifelse(post>threshold,"+","-")
```

seems sufficiently simple that you might not even need to package it in a function.

Or you could use

```
predicted <- function(post,threshold=0.5,alt=c("+","-"))
      ifelse(post>threshold,alt[1],alt[2])
```

Alternatively

```
predicted <- function(post,threshold=0.5,alt=c("+","-"))
   alt[1+(post<=threshold)]
```

would probably be marginally faster (`post>threshold` gives a logical vector, which is coerced to 0/1 when added to 1, resulting in 1 for "below" and 2 for "above"). Or you could reverse the order of `alt`, as @DWin does in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
pred <- c("-", "+")[1+(post > 0.5)]
```

Comment: I put it in because it seem the most vectorized. I think earlier SO investigations have shown it to be inferior to `ifelse` in terms of speed (and clarity).

Comment: ah nice way as well !